# Multiple Root Tags Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

i'm new to xml, and i can't get past "Multiple Root Tags" error, i`ve read others questions, but nothing seems to work, how can i fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="@strig/quantity"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: add the log that appear in android studio here to see what happened in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/Quantity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:text="@strig/quantity"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout can only have one top-level tag. Yours currently has two (the ConstraintLayout and the LinearLayout). Probably you did not mean to end the ConstraintLayout tag with `/>`; remove the slash and add a closing tag at the bottom of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, your syntax is incorrect

```
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Try with this